# Exemplo do ASP.NET Identity usando o SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Ainda uso apenas o `FormsAuthentication` mas procurei e não encontrei um exemplo, mesmo que mínimo, em **português** que fale sobre o ASP.NET Identity para o MVC.

Estou usando o ASP.NET MVC 5 e o EntityFramework 6.1, gostaria de aprender sobre o ASP.NET Identity mas estou tendo dificuldade em enteder o template MVC com ***`Individual User Account`***.

Alguém poderia dar um exemplo **básico** (para não ser amplo e não fugir do escopo do **SOpt**), **partindo do template web MVC sem autenticação** (***`No Authentication`***)?

Comment: @Crood Você diz asp net identity utilizando WIF?

Comment: WIF é o o Windows Identity Foundation, tem a ver com certificados digitais (smart cards) e isso tb se chama Identity. Outro nome também para o Identity é Federated Authentication.. se for isso ai, eu tenho um projeto que roda 100% e posso postar aqui pra vc

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Esta resposta é o básico do básico para se ter uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC5 usando ASP.NET Identity com *Individual User Accounts*, conforme solicitado pela pergunta. Portanto, não pretendo adensar a resposta falando sobre tudo o que o ASP.NET Identity faz. Poderei falar mais sobre o assunto em uma outra pergunta mais específica.

## A mais básica das aplicações

Inicialmente a ideia é criar uma aplicação autossuficiente com o mínimo que uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC5 precisa ter.

#### Primeiro Passo: Crie um Projeto no Visual Studio 2013

- Nos grupos de templates, escolha Web, depois ASP.NET Web Application;
  [image: Criando projeto]
- Na tela de tipos de projetos, escolha MVC. Nenhuma outra opção é necessária:
  [image: Projeto MVC]
- O Visual Studio irá criar o projeto.

#### Segundo Passo: Atualize os Pacotes da Solução

Possivelmente o Visual Studio iniciará um projeto com pacotes desatualizados, que são propensos a bugs.

- Vá em View > Other Windows > Package Manager Console:
  [image: Package Manager Console]
- Digite `Update-Package` e <kbd>Enter</kbd>:
  [image: Update-Package]
- O Visual Studio atualizará todos os pacotes. Talvez você precise reiniciar o Visual Studio.

#### Terceiro Passo: Teste

- Execute sua solução apertando <kbd>F5</kbd>;
- Ao aparecer a primeira tela, clique em `Register`;
- Escolha um nome de usuário, uma senha, e clique em `Register`;
- Se for registrado um usuário pra você sem erros, a aplicação está funcionando com *Individual User Accounts*:
  [image: Sucesso no Registro]

### Conclusões

Repare que até aqui não foi mencionado nem banco de dados, nem conexão, nem nada relacionado a configuração. É possível repetir estes passos em cinco minutos, dependendo da velocidade do seu computador. Algumas observações são importantes aqui.

#### 1. Na verdade existe um banco de dados

O banco de dados é um arquivo `.mdf` local, criado para hospedar os dados do ASP.NET Identity descritos mais acima.

Para vê-lo, faça o seguinte:

- Na janela `Solution Explorer`, clique no botão `Show All Files`:
  [image: Show All Files]
- Repare que aparecerá um diretório chamado `App_Data`, com um arquivo oculto dentro. Executando duplo clique nele, aparecerá outra janela detalhando o arquivo:
  [image: Tabelas do ASP.NET Identity]
- Expanda o ítem `DefaultConnection` que apareceu na janela nova. Expanda também o ítem `Tables`. Você poderá ver todas as tabelas que o ASP.NET Identity cria para o projeto.

#### 2. É possível migrar o banco para o SQL Server Express

Antes de realizar esta etapa, certifique-se de que o SQL Server 2012 Express esteja instalado na sua máquina.

Primeiro, repare que a `ConnectionString` do seu arquivo `web.config` aponta para o tal arquivo local já mencionado. Por exemplo:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TesteMaroto-20140518034350.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TesteMaroto-20140518034350;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Sendo assim, não faz muito sentido criar uma migração desta forma. Então primeiro precisamos apontar a `DefaultConnection` para o banco SQL Server Express instalado.

Minha sugestão:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-TesteMaroto-20140518034350.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-TesteMaroto-20140518034350;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" / -->
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TesteMaroto.Models.TesteMarotoContext;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Agora sim precisamos criar uma Migration para o banco. Isso pode ser feito novamente pelo `Package Manager Console`, digitando o seguinte:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations
```

Só que, ao digitar isso, tive a seguinte mensagem:

> Migrations have already been enabled in project 'TesteMaroto'. To overwrite the existing migrations configuration, use the -Force parameter.

Ou seja, já temos `Migrations` ativadas. Para quem conhece bem `Migrations`, basta usar o seguinte comando:

```
PM> Add-Migration Inicial
```

O Visual Studio criará um arquivo, exatamente com as tabelas que vimos no arquivo local. Para efetivar as mudanças no SQL Server Express, basta executar o comando:

```
PM> Update-Database
```

E pronto! Experimente executar novamente seu site, e depois confira os dados no seu SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 20):

Vou postar o que eu consegui e conforme for, vou incrementando.

### A Autenticação pelo *ASP.NET*

Há bastante tempo, o ***ASP.NET*** oferece suporte a dois tipos básicos de autenticação: autenticação do *Windows* e autenticação de formulários.
A autenticação de formulários, é uma abordagem que foi amplamente adotada. Para cada acesso a um recurso protegido, o aplicativo garante que a solicitação inclua um cookie de autenticação válido. É simples e funciona.

#### O Provedor de Associação (*MembershipProvider*)

Em **2005**, com o lançamento do ***ASP.NET 2.0***, a *Microsoft* introduziu diretamente na estrutura uma arquitetura baseada no provedor e o provedor de associação. Em vez de recriar o esquema de autenticação toda vez, você poderia simplesmente gerar a associação do sistema interno e substituir apenas as funções que pretende alterar.

O ***ASP.NET*** apresenta um provedor de associação padrão que se baseia em um determinado esquema de banco de dados. No entanto, você pode escrever com facilidade seu próprio provedor de associação para atingir basicamente um banco de dados diferente, geralmente, um banco de dados de usuários existente.

Com o tempo, várias pessoas que tentavam repetidamente criar um provedor de associação personalizado começaram a reclamar sobre o detalhamento da interface. Na verdade, o provedor de associação se apresenta na forma de uma classe base hereditária, MembershipProvider, que inclui mais de 30 membros marcados como abstratos. Isso significa que para qualquer novo provedor de associação que você desejasse criar, havia, pelo menos, 30 membros a serem substituídos. O que é ainda pior, você realmente não precisava de muitos deles a maior parte do tempo. Havia necessidade de uma arquitetura de associação mais simples.

#### O Provedor de Associação Simples (*Simple Membership Provider*), com a classe ***ExtendedMembershipProvider***

A *Microsoft* apresentou outra opção com o ***Visual Studio 2010 SP1***: a **API** de associação simples. Originalmente disponível no ***WebMatrix*** e em Páginas da Web, a API de associação simples tornou-se uma maneira bastante popular de gerenciar a autenticação, especialmente no ***ASP.NET MVC***.

A associação simples permite que você trabalhe com qualquer repositório de dados que possua e exige apenas que você indique quais colunas na tabela têm a função de nome de usuário e ID de usuário.
A principal diferença da API de associação clássica é uma lista significativamente mais curta de parâmetros para quaisquer métodos. Além disso, você ganha muito mais liberdade no que diz respeito ao esquema de armazenamento de associação.

#### O *ASP.NET Identity*

Surgiu com o Visual Studio 2013 e o ASP.NET 5.
O ***ASP.NET Identity***, se baseia em dois blocos principais: o gerenciador de autenticação e o gerenciador de armazenamento. Na estrutura do ***ASP.NET Identity***, o gerenciador de autenticação usa o formulário da classe ***UserManager***. Essa classe fornece basicamente uma fachada para que os usuários entrem e saiam. O gerenciador de armazenamento é uma instância da classe ***UserStore***.

Vou seguir com um exemplo baseado em um projeto ***ASP.NET Web Application*** com o template **MVC** sem autenticação (***No Authentication***). Ou seja, vou seguir do zero na implementação do ***ASP.NET Identity*** na aplicação.

Primeiramente precisei adicionar instalar o pacote ***Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework*** ao projeto (para o exemplo não vou implementar as camadas em projetos ***Class Libraries*** separadas), que por sua vez instalou outros pacotes como o próprio ***EntityFramework*** e o ***Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core***.

Com isso já pude criar a minha classe que representará o usuário:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace ASPNETIdentity.Example.Models
{
    public class Usuario : IdentityUser { }
}
```

A classe usuário com certeza pode ser **[extendida](http://eduardopires.net.br/2014/03/asp-net-identity-customizando-cadastro-usuarios/)**.

Basicamente, o contexto de banco de dados do ASP.NET Identity trata da persistência de um determinado tipo de usuário. O tipo de usuário deve implementar a interface IUser ou apenas herdar de IdentityUser.

O tipo de usuário deve implementar a interface *`IUser`* ou apenas herdar de *`IdentityUser`*.
Nada a princípio precisará ser implementado pois a classe *`IdentityUser`* já possui muito das propriedades e métodos necessários.

```
public class IdentityUser : IUser
{
    public IdentityUser();
    public IdentityUser(string userName);

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserClaim> Claims { get; }
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserLogin> Logins { get; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole> Roles { get; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Esse exemplo foi copiado da web, provavelmente uma versão antes do *EntityFramewor 6.1*. Estou utilizando o *EntityFramework 6.1* e nele a classe *`IdentityUser`* está assim:

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim> : IUser<TKey>
    where TLogin : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
    where TRole : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole<TKey>
    where TClaim : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
{
    public IdentityUser();
    public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TClaim> Claims { get; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TLogin> Logins { get; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TRole> Roles { get; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Com o meu modelo/domínio pronto, que é apenas a classe `Usuario`, já posso criar meu contexto do banco de dados.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace ASPNETIdentity.Example.Repository
{
    public class AuthenticationContext : IdentityDbContext<Models.Usuario>
    {
        public AuthenticationContext() :
            base("Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=IdExample; Integrated Security=True")
        { }
    }
}
```

> Após isso habilitei o ***Migrations*** e já foi possível criar o banco e dados.

Em seguida criei minha classe *`Controller`* para `Usuario`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ASPNETIdentity.Example.Controllers
{
    public class UsuarioController : Controller
    {
        public UserManager<Models.Usuario> UserManager { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="manager">The UserManager</param>
        public UsuarioController(UserManager<Models.Usuario> manager)
        {
            UserManager = manager;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public UsuarioController()
            : this(new UserManager<Models.Usuario>(
                new UserStore<Models.Usuario>(new Repository.AuthenticationContext())
                )) { }
    }
}
```

Estou começando a ler sobre Desing Patterns agora, mas esse me parece um pouco com o padrão *Estrategy*.

Vou ficar por aqui!
Talvez eu volte mais tarde implementando um pouco mais, agora sobre como trabalhar com o UsuarioController.
Mas ainda assim o exemplo de uso pode ser encontrado no template ***MVC*** com o ***Individual User Account***.
A verificação das permissões de acesso pode ser feito no restante da aplicação com o `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Correções e melhorias são bem vindas.
Melhores respostas ainda mais!!

Fonte: ***[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/magazine/dn605872.aspx)***

Comment: Algo que ficou fora da resposta e considero muito importante, é o conceito de `Claims`, em que um login é na verdade um conjunto de identificações de várias tecnologias combinadas (por exemplo, Active Directory, OAuth, Kerberos...). Estou tentando responder a questão faz uns vários dias, mas minha máquina não parou de fazer updates até então. No que eu conseguir coloco os passos aqui.

Comment: Eu li tudo sim :) ta muito boa a respota +1
Sobre o seu comentário sobre Claims, esse assunto é dar pano pra manga rs, tem muita coisa pra explicar... por que explicar sobre Claims Aware authenticatino, tem que falar do Federated Authentication, e explicar como funciona  a emissão dos tokens e muito blabla pra vc consumir com meia duzia de linha de codigo rs

Comment: @Crood Exatamente. Acho que ela merece um tratamento em separado. Seu esboço me parece ótimo pra começar uma nova pergunta.