# ASP.NET Identity e Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net, autenticação, asp.net-identity

Ainda sobre *ASP.NET Identity*, seguindo uma outra pergunta que fiz a respeito disso (**[Exemplo do ASP.NET Identity usando o SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server)**), um tema interessante dentro do mesmo assunto seria a respeito de *`Claims`*.

**Do que se trata? Como seria uma implementação básica para fins didáticos?**

Comment: Já favoritei. Vou responder no tempo livre.

Comment: Acho que isso ta respondido na sua outra pergunta.. nao tem como uma coisa ser explicada sem a outra rs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Do que se trata?

**Claims** são parcelas de dados que formam uma identidade. Uma identidade é toda e qualquer informação utilizada para identificar unicamente um usuário.

## Uma implementação básica, para fins didáticos

[Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/alikl/windows-identity-foundation-wif-by-example-part-iii-how-to-implement-claims-based-authorization-for-asp-net-application) tem um exemplo bem completo, em inglês. Como o exemplo é muito grande, não acho que valha a pena colar ele aqui.

Entretanto, se o exemplo não for suficiente, vou bolar um projeto para demonstrar o funcionamento e hospedá-lo no GitHub.

Comment: Questão salva pelo gongo! (rs) Ou melhor, pelo Cigano..

Comment: Seria possível revisar essa resposta?