# Usar tabela do Banco de Dados, ao invés de tabela criada ao usar Autenticação Individual com Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Eu criei uma aplicação em Asp.net MVC usando Identity e deixei marcada a opção para o Visual Studio criar a autenticação de usuários individuais para mim. Acontece que eu só descobri que ele cria um arquivo .mdf que contém um banco de dados e tabelas para armazenar registros de usuários. Eu não sabia disso e acabei criando uma outra tabela para o meu sistema com as regras de negócio e etc. Quando eu coloquei a aplicação no servidor, logicamente, esse arquivo .mdf com o banco de dados e suas tabelas não foram e aí eu não pude usar a autenticação. Daí eu até agora vi que tenho algumas opções:

1 - Criar as mesmas tabelas que exatamente iguais no BD que eu já uso no SQL Server e usar a conexão de "DefaultConnection" para a conexão que estou usando do Entity. Para esta opção, está dando erro na minha aplicação ao tentar criar usuário ou logar (já que coloquei usuários manualmente no BD):

```
Detalhes da Exceção: System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

Erro de Origem: 

Linha 74:             // Isso não conta falhas de login em relação ao bloqueio de conta
Linha 75:             // Para permitir que falhas de senha acionem o bloqueio da conta, altere para shouldLockout: true
Linha 76:             var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
Linha 77:             switch (result)
Linha 78:             {

Arquivo de Origem: c:\Users\sydvagner.franco\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LPGPonto\LPGPonto\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Linha: 76
```

2 - Tentar usar os dois banco de dados para essa aplicação. Acho meio bizarro, mas aceitaria se fosse o mais simples. Nesse caso eu migraria o BD para o SQL Server (já vi que isso é possível, mas ainda não tentei) ou colocaria o arquivo .mdf no servidor, alterando o Web.config para acessar esse arquivo no local que eu colocá-lo no servidor, ao invés de em  |DataDirectory| como vem por Default que é a pasta App_Data da aplicação (Essa pasta não aparece depois do deploy do sistema, por isso não existe o arquivo .mdf criado automaticamente para controle de autenticação).

### Funcionamento do Sistema

É um sistema de Ponto Eletrônico que tem as tabelas:

1. DIARIA
2. FERIADO
3. FERIAS
4. FUNÇÃO
5. FUNCIONÁRIO
6. LOCAL
7. REGISTRO (que guarda o IP e a hora do registro de ponto).
8. AspNetRoles (peguei o script e gerei a tabela igual à criada pelo Identity)
9. AspNetUsers (peguei o script e gerei a tabela igual à criada pelo Identity)

### Tabelas geradas no BD automaticamente para controlar autenticação do usuário

1. MigrationHistory
2. AspNetRoles
3. AspNetUsersLogins
4. AspNetUserRoles
5. AspNetUsers

Eu só coloquei as tabelas AspNetUsers e AspNetRoles porque achei que só vou utilizar essas.

Comment: Você pode colocar na sua pergunta essa definição das suas tabelas pra que eu possa ter uma ideia de como é o funcionamento desse sistema?

Comment: Exatamente Tiago Silva. O arquivo .mdf foi criado antes de eu mudar. Mas eu já alterei a connection string para usar a mesma conexão criada com o Entity para acessar o BD que eu criei.

Comment: [Naquela resposta que eu dei](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16220/2999), você fez o procedimento pra gerar uma Migration e subir seu banco em um SQL Server?

Comment: Não fiz isso ainda Cigano, pois já uso um BD, como falei e não queria usar dois BD para uma mesma aplicação. Mas se você me disser que não tem jeito, que terei que fazer isso para dar certo, eu farei.

Comment: @TiagoSilva o meu ApplicationDbContext ficou assim: 
public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("PONTOEntities")
            //: base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

A parte comentada era a conexão anterior com DefaultConnection

Comment: @SydinhoFranco Faça quando puder. Você não tem vantagem alguma trabalhando com .mdf.

Comment: Então ok @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu vou fazer isso e dou um retorno.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez eu tentei fazer a migração, porém deu esse erro: "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'." A minha connection string ficou assim: "<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=LPG-11;Initial Catalog=LPGPonto.Models.LPGPontoContext;Integrated Security=True;user id=sa;password=123master!@#" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />" Mesmo passando o usuário e senha do "sa" o SQL Server não forneceu acesso para criar as tabelas?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez tudo certo. No seu tutorial o "DefaultConnection" estava com "Integrated Security=True". Eu troquei pra False e funcionou. Agora estou usando os dois BD para a mesma aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz a migração (conforme mostrado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16220#16220)) do banco de dados criado automaticamente pelo Identity para controlar a autenticação de usuários no sistema para o meu servidor de BD SQL Server e agora estou usando os dois bancos de dados para a mesma aplicação. Foi o jeito que foi dado por não ter feito a migração desse banco antes e ter utilizado esse mesmo banco para os dados gerais da minha aplicação. Então, a minha dica é que sempre que alguém deixar marcada a opção para o Identity criar a autenticação para usuário, migrar esse banco de dados para o SQL Server e usar esse mesmo banco para inserir outras tabelas da aplicação, para não precisar usar 2 banco de dados para o mesmo sistema.