# Autenticação padrão do Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou iniciando estudos sobre o asp.net MVC, e queria saber onde é que o visual studio cria o banco e tabelas quando se escolhe o projeto padrão MVC.
Ao que parece ele já cria todo o suporte para registro e login. Onde ficam essas tabelas ? Posso migrar isso para um banco mysql, por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Onde ficam essas tabelas?

No diretório `App_Data` fica um banco provisório no formato `LocalDb`, mas esse arquivo fica escondido. No **Solution Explorer**, clique no botão *Show All Files* para vê-lo:

[image: Show All Files]

## Posso migrar isso para um banco mysql, por exemplo?

Pode. Primeiro você precisa [configurar o Entity Framework para MySQL](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264), e depois executar o comando `Update-Database` para popular seu banco. [Esta resposta ensina como fazer isso para SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16220#16220), mas serve também para o MySQL.

Comment: Valeu Cigano, funcionou beleza no vs2013. Agora estou testando o vNext e esse diretório App_Data nem existe mais.

Comment: @paulo Ah, sim. A aplicação que eu colei de exemplo ainda é MVC5.

Comment: Acabei descobrindo que o banco de dados ele cria em c:\Usuarios\seuusuario

Comment: @paulo É normal variar. Tudo depende de como o projeto é iniciado.