# Como fazer sistema de login no site usando conta do Instagram, Twitter ou Google+ em Plataforma .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, instagram-api, twitter-api

Estou querendo desenvolver algo do tipo mas não tenho referencias de como fazer, poderiam me ajudar com algum exemplo?

Comment: Apesar de não parecer, a pergunta é ótima. Terá meu voto para reabrir caso seja fechada.

Comment: Olá Gabriel. O SOPT não é um fórum, e sim um site de perguntas e respostas objetivas. A sua pergunta é muito ampla, porque explicações sobre como desenvolver um sistema de login (ainda mais em várias tecnologias distintas) daria muitas respostas ou respostas muito longas. Você poderia editar a pergunta para torná-la mais específica, principalmente oferencendo parte do que você já tentou fazer. Também leia, por favor, as seções [help] e [ask].

Comment: @LuizVieira Discordo. Para o caso específico do .NET, a metodologia é bem definida e não se trata de algo tão amplo assim. Essa é uma daquelas perguntas que fazem parte da zona cinza do conhecimento específico de área. Não há qualquer problema com ela. Vide resposta que coloquei, cujo roteiro de criação é bem conhecido.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Hum... você tem razão. Só vi o seu comentário depois (votei pra fechar pela fila de análise). Desculpe, vou votar para reabrir (e obrigado pelo aviso).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comece por um sistema de exemplo do ASP.NET Identity. [Nesta resposta ensino o passo a passo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16220#16220).

Deve ser criados dois arquivos automáticos no processo:

- `Startup.cs` (diretório raiz);
- `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs`.

`Startup.cs` chama `Startup.Auth.cs`. Repare que `Startup.Auth.cs` deverá ter as seguintes linhas:

```
        // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        //    clientId: "",
        //    clientSecret: "");

        //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        //   consumerKey: "",
        //   consumerSecret: "");

        //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //   appId: "",
        //   appSecret: "");

        //app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        //{
        //    ClientId = "",
        //    ClientSecret = ""
        //});
```

É aqui que são configurados os provedores de integração com os serviços mais consagrados da internet.

Adicionalmente, é criada uma *Partial* (`Views/Account/_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml`) que cria os botões para a integração com os provedores configurados em `Startup.Auth.cs`.

Para o caso do Instagram, [há ainda o excelente pacote Auth0](https://auth0.com/authenticate/aspnet/instagram) que simplifica todo o processo pra você.