# Como iniciar no MVC5 ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

Olá! Mais ou menos a um mês comecei a me aventurar pelo mundo do C# e depois comecei a estudar o Framework .Net. Logo após passei a estudar também ASP.NET devido a necessidade em minha empresa. Hoje utilizo o Visual Studio 2013 para criar Web Apps com o padrão MVC, do qual eu já trabalhei a anos em PHP.

O Visual Studio cria todos os diretórios, rotas das URLs, entre outros arquivos de configuração, isso é ótimo. Mas eu gostaria de realmente construir uma vez pelo menos uma aplicação .NET no padrão MVC 5 uma vez, para realmente saber como o Framework funciona. Alguém teria alguma dica de livro, site, funções da qual eu teria que começar a estudar?

Por exemplo, em código C e em outras linguagens a aplicação começa pelo `void main`. Em asp.net como funciona a configuração para inicializar o aplicativo. E como faço o arquivo de Rotas, enfim. Basicamente como faço a aplicação funcionar.

Sei que em um ambiente de produção não iria criar na mão, mas como programador acho importante saber como as coisas funcionam no *back-end*, não é mágica!

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Sua pergunta está ampla, tente deixar ela mais especifica, o stackoverflow funciona diferente de um fórum pode ver as diferenças na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) veja esse [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tem dicas de como elaborar uma pergunta e bem vindo \o.

Comment: Então Raniery. Primeiramente acessa [o site oficial do asp.net mvc](http://asp.net/mvc). Nesse link tem vários tutoriais sobre a tecnologia, e de uma básica, a uma um pouco mais aprofundada. Outra referencia é o [site da k19](http://k19.com.br) e a Caelum também é uma fonte de referência. Mas o intuito do SOpt é ajudar com códigos feitos, olhe esses links, tente fazer e volte aqui pra ajudarmos em algum erro. =]

Comment: O Livro "Programando com ASP.NET MVC" de Alfredo Lotar é muito bom pra quem esta começando, já aprendi bastante. Não estou craque, pq comecei a ler a pouco tempo, porém o livro ensina direitinho as funções básicas.

Comment: Começa pelo básico: O Nome correto é `Asp.Net MVC`

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 4):

[Comece por esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16220#16220). Vou partir dela para continuar.

## A estrutura básica de um Projeto ASP.MET MVC

Criei meu projeto, posso ligá-lo a uma base do SQL Server Express, e tenho algo muito parecido com isso:

[image: Solution Explorer]

- **App_Data**: Diretório que guarda bases de dados locais, como LocalDb;
- **App_Start**: Classes invocadas para iniciar a aplicação;
- **Content**: Arquivos que normalmente fazem parte da apresentação, como imagens e folhas de estilo (CSS);
- **Controllers**: As entidades controladoras da aplicação. Organizam as requisições feitas ao sistema e harmonizam as entidades de dados (*Models*);
- **fonts**: Diretório de fontes;
- **Migrations**: Diretório que guarda as migrações incrementais da base de dados. Normalmente é usada com o Entity Framework, que é instalado por padrão no projeto ASP.NET MVC;
- **Models**: A descrição das entidades de dados e as relações entre elas. Dentro de um conceito DDD, seria o domínio da aplicação;
- **Scripts**: Diretório para programação da apresentação. Normalmente guarda arquivos JavaScript;
- **Views**: Diretórios e arquivos da camada de apresentação. Não necessariamente é HTML, mas por padrão, é. *Views* são escritas usando a notação **Razor**.

## O "Hello, World" (ou equivalente) no MVC5

Como escolhi a opção de ASP.NET Identity, 3 *Controllers* são criados:

- `AccountController.cs`;
- `HomeController.cs`;
- `ManageController.cs`;

O que é sempre criado é o `HomeController.cs`. Ele normalmente vem assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Teste.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

O método `Index` seria o mais próximo de um "Hello, World" que podemos ter. Ao iniciarmos o site, é a primeira requisição que o sistema atende. Experimente executar e colocar um *breakpoint* no `return View()` para confirmar isso.

## Ciclo Básico

No caso de `Index`, que tem uma instrução só:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Pedimos para que seja retornada uma *View* sem passar nada pra ela. Como não informamos o nome dela, o MVC irá procurar em `Views/Home` por um arquivo chamado `Index.cshtml`. Se não encontrar, irá procurar por outras extensões cujo nome comece com `Index` e depois irá procurar por `Index` dentro de `Views/Shared`.

Aliás, é em `Views/Shared` que fica o *layout* principal do sistema, as telas prontas de login e uma tela padrão de erros.

Repare que o método retorna um `ActionResult`. `ActionResult` pode ser muitas coisas:

- Uma *View*;
- Um redirecionamento para outra *Action*;
- Um arquivo;
- Uma resposta para requisição crua;
- Um JSON;
- Um XML;
- etc., etc., etc.

Não vou entrar em detalhes sobre isso para não alongar demais a pergunta.

## ViewBag

Repare que nos outros métodos temos o uso de `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

    return View();
}
```

`ViewBag` é um objeto dinâmico auxiliar para preencher a *View* com algumas informações úteis. **Não deve ser usado para informações persistidas**. É excelente para mensagens, identificadores úteis e pequenos controles. **Nunca** deve ser usado para regras complexas de negócio.

## E agora?

Temos várias perguntas que podem servir como próximos passos no seu aprendizado. [Temos o site do ASP.NET MVC com seus tutoriais](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started). A tag [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) tem um Wiki interno com mais informações e material para estudo. Precisando de mais, pode abrir uma pergunta [ou entrar no chat e tirar sua dúvida com a gente](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25342/c-asp-net-asp-net-mvc-entity-framework-etc).

Comment: Muito obrigado!