# Template MVC 5 ou outro: formulário inicial de usuários, informações, banco de dados

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Os templates que vêm no VS2013 ou qualquer outra versão, ao iniciar um projeto, ele monta um menu com: *Home*, *About*, *Contact*, *Register* e *Login*.

Pergunto: Como ele guarda as informações dos registros de novos usuários padrão? Onde fica armazenado?

Answer (score 1):

> Precisei adequar a pergunta original para responder porque a pergunta não fazia sentido, diante da dúvida original do autor. Manterei a resposta com a versão original e as alterações mais abaixo por razões históricas, visto que o sentido da pergunta mudou completamente com a edição. Para fins da resposta, favor considerar apenas a segunda seção, "onde os dados ficam gravados".

## Onde ficam os templates do Visual Studio?

Os *templates* normalmente ficam aqui:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates

Aí os diretórios são divididos por padrão de projeto. Por exemplo, projetos Web em C# ficam aqui:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web

Arquivos `.vstemplate` são arquivos XML. Você pode abri-los no seu editor de texto de sua preferência.

Há também os arquivos `.tt` e `.t4`, que são arquivos de template de transformação. São usados para a técnica de *Scaffolding*. [Escrevi este artigo sobre *Scaffolding* explicando o princípio geral](http://masterdesigners.com.br/a-era-dos-pre-moldados-scaffolding/).

---

## Onde são armazenadas, inicialmente, informações de usuários em aplicações geradas por *template* no Visual Studio?

[Para o caso do ASP.NET Identity, respondi aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16220#16220). Também vale para o Membership.

Para a geração anterior de formulários da época do Web Forms (chamada de Simple Membership), havia duas maneiras:

- [Usando ferramenta para registro no SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229862%28v=vs.100%29.aspx);
- [Chamando `SqlServices.Install` no seu código em algum momento](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.management.sqlservices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Ou seja, para Membership e tecnologias mais recentes, o padrão é um arquivo `.mdb` dentro do diretório `App_Data` do seu próprio projeto. Para tecnologias anteriores, depende.

Comment: Olá, acho que não fui claro na pergunta. A pergunta é: Como eu recupero os dados gravados quando o usuário registra, usando o form Register que vem com o ele. Um colega em outro site me respondeu isso: Ah sim, então, ele cria uma estrutura no localdb. Veja no Webconfig da aplicação a connection string do banco de dados para descobrir o nome do banco de dados criado. As informações estarão lá.

Comment: @pnet Editei a resposta.