# Como resolver erro com OWIN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

Bem amigos, criei um projeto Web Asp.Net MVC `No Authentication`, mas agora estou precisando da autenticação.

Estou seguindo alguns tutoriais como [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16190#16190) para colocar autenticação do zero, mas após instalar o [EntityFramework](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.1.3) e [OWIN](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/) tive problemas ao executar o projeto:

> **No owin.Environment item was found in the context.**
>
> **Descrição**: Ocorreu uma exceção sem tratamento durante a execução da
> atual solicitação da Web. Examine o rastreamento de pilha para obter
> mais informações sobre o erro e onde foi originado no código.
>
> **Detalhes da Exceção:** System.InvalidOperationException: No owin.Environment item was found in the context.

Alguém sabe o por que e como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Esse cara aqui "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650168/no-owin-environment-item-was-found-in-the-context-only-on-server" Resolveu reiniciando o server.

Comment: Reiniciei, mas infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: Você criou outro? Se pode começar um novo, escolhe com autenticação. Expanda a árvore de arquivos do seu projeto, no ***Solution Explorer***, e envie uma imagem dos arquivos contidos que você criou para o ***ASP.NET Identity***.

Comment: Bem amigo, esse é o maior problema! Não posso criar outro projeto com Authentication e migrar meu projeto atual pra lá. Estou usando o Telerik e se fizesse isso ele não iria funcionar. Tem que ser nesse projeto que já estou trabalhando.

Comment: @Jedaias, ok, então tente dar uma melhor posição sobre o que você tem já feito do Identity.

Comment: Bem, importei (copiei e colei) as classes `IdentityModels` e `AccountViewModels` de um outro projeto criado que usa o `Authentication` , também estou usando as classes `AccountController` e `IdentityConfig` da mesma forma. Mas através do `Package Manager Console` instalei o `EntityFramwork` e o `OWIN`.

Comment: A `Startup.cs`, copiou?

Comment: Não havia copiado não, copiei agora, mas o mesmo erro continua. Acredito que devo configurar algo no `Web.config`

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa criar uma Statup Class:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

- Verifique se há uma *Startup Class* no seu projeto;
- Verifique se a *Startup Class* possui a seguinte anotação antes da declaração da classe:

  ```
  [assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MeuProjeto.Startup))]
  ```