# Fazer programa em c# que rode online

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Olá, sou iniciante em programação e já mexi um pouco com c# mas bem pouco!
No meu trabalho foi colocada uma proposta para eu fazer um programa em c#, html ou java para armazenar o lançamento dos faturamentos da empresa (empresa pequena) e como eu sou a única da parte de informática o filho é meu rs
Como nunca mexi com java integrado com banco de dados nem html estou pensando em fazer o formulário em C# para os dados serem armazenados no servidor aqui da empresa e meu chefe gostaria que tivesse a possibilidade de ser feita a consulta e o lançamento dos dados via web também. Abrir o programa, estar conectado na internet, digitar os dados e pimba, estão no banco de dados do servidor mesmo sem ser rede local. É possível isso? E se sim, alguém poderia me ajudar dando algum site legal ou algo do tipo? É meu primeiro emprego, sou estagiária ainda mas, quero fazer bem feito!
Desde já obrigada!

Answer (score 4):

Para o desenvolvimento da página se comunicando com o banco de dados sendo offline/online você vai utilizar alguma linguagem de programação que no seu caso seria `C#` ou `Java`.

No caso do `Html` é apenas uma linguagem de marcação, é com ele que você "monta" a página e o navegador mostra para o usuário. Dependendo se você utilizar `WebForms C#` você nem precisa conhecer muito de `Html` porque ele vai gerar tudo automático conforme os componentes utilizados.

Como sua necessidade aborda muitas coisas eu aconselho procurar algum tutorial ou video aula sobre `WebForms C#`, não da para simplesmente te passar os códigos. Depois que você conseguir construir seu site só resta você hospedar ele e será possível acessar de qualquer lugar.

Então segue a sequência de estudo:

- Diferença entre Linguagem de programação e Linguagem de marcação.
- Desenvolvimento de páginas com `WebForms` em `C#`
- Comunicação com o banco de dados, caso você for utilizar a IDE `Visual Studio` a integração com o `SQL Server` é muito simples.
- Hospedagem de aplicações WEB.

Estude!

Comment: Sim, vou estudar e muito para fazê-lo, também porque não quero simplesmente fazer quero aprender. Só queria mesmo saber se é possível, por exemplo, criar o programa pelo `Visual Studio C#`, criar um banco de dados e depois integrá-los online. Pelo que você disse, entendi que seria "mais fácil" fazer a página em `html` e usar os formulários `html` para inserção e visualização dos dados do banco.

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-web-project-visual-studio-e-c/20168

Comment: Só para deixar claro que com C# para a WEB a palavra chave é **ASP.NET**. O **WebForms** é apenas um jeito de usar o ASP.NET. Apesar do WebForms parecer mais simples a principio, eu recomendaria para quem está começando usar o ASP.NET MVC, pois abstrai menos o HTML e a comunicação HTTP. Se ela vai ter que aprender a programar para a Web é melhor fazer isso de uma maneira mais transparente.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Para quem tem facilidade com programação e entende o fluxo realmente MVC é mais fácil, mas para aprendizado eu acredito que o WebForms é mais fácil.

Comment: @kaamis Aqui tem um exemplo com banco de dados: http://csharpbrasil.com.br/desenvolvimento-de-website-com-asp-net-e-sql-server-parte-1/

Comment: Obrigada pessoal, vou dar uma olhada e vou construindo aos poucos. Recebi a proposta hoje, ainda não tenho prazo de entrega mas, como nunca mexi com essa integração online já quero ir garantindo uma base no que estudar pelo menos. Ainda mais que estou praticamente sozinha nessa.

Answer (score 0):

A tecnologia de ponta para construção de soluções Web em C# se chama ASP.NET MVC. Há algumas tags pra ela aqui no site, como [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), [asp.net-mvc-4](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4) e [asp.net-mvc-5](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5). Você pode ver as perguntas e respostas nessas tags ou buscar tutoriais em http://asp.net/mvc.

[Fiz uma resposta com uma cara de tutorial que também pode ser usada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15485/exemplo-do-asp-net-identity-usando-o-sql-server/16220#16220). Ela é bem prática e leva apenas alguns minutos para montar um site com algumas telas.